# LDAP cannot authenticate

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, rhel

I was following this guide to setup an LDAP server on CentOS 6.6: http://www.learnitguide.net/2016/01/configure-openldap-server-on-rhel7.html. I know the guide is for RHEL, but I think the vast majority of steps should be the same. I went through the tutorial and everything seems to work right except for sshing into the server as an LDAP user. As root I am able to su to any LDAP user. getent passwd username returns appropriate results. But every time I try to ssh in as a user I get permission denied and these messages show up in /var/log/secure:

```
Aug  8 22:13:14 servername sshd[5900]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=rhostname  user=username
Aug  8 22:13:14 servername sshd[5900]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=rhostname user=username
Aug  8 22:13:14 servername sshd[5900]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user username: 6 (Permission denied)
Aug  8 22:13:17 servername sshd[5900]: Failed password for username from rhostIPaddress port 34758 ssh2
```

I was hoping maybe someone may know of a step that guide left out that would cause this behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the self signed certificate I was using needed to have the IP address as the common name as opposed to the FQDN, not sure why that is but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Information that can help others.
In my case this message was a time difference problem between the FreeIPA server and the clients. The command systemctl status sssd -l presented the message (skew clock too great).
This message from the Kerberos authentication server appears if the difference hour in servers is too large (more than three or four minutes).

OS: Ubuntu Server